# как узнать что div зашел за пределы родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```css
.block {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 300px;
    height: 300px; 
}
.block__inner--1{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 background: #ffd1d1
}
.block__inner--2{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 background: #d1e7ff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="block">
  <div class="block__inner--1">block 1</div>
  <div class="block__inner--2">block 2</div>
 </div>
```

как можно поставить условие на js , если **block__inner--2** вышел за границу **block** то вывести в консоль сообщение

```css
.block {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 300px;
    height: 300px; 
}
.block__inner--1{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
    height: 240px;
 background: #ffd1d1
}
.block__inner--2{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 background: #d1e7ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
 <div class="block__inner--1">block 1</div>
 <div class="block__inner--2">block 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Узнать-то - дело нехитрое. Вам надо продумать, по какому событию Вы будете отслеживать - выходит блок или не выходит. При загрузке страницы проверяется так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let innerBlock = $(".block__inner--2").offset().top + $(".block__inner--2").outerHeight();

  let block = $(".block").offset().top + $(".block").outerHeight();

  if(innerBlock > block) {
    console.log('Блок вышел за пределы')
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 300px;
    height: 300px; 
}
.block__inner--1{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
    height: 240px;
 background: #ffd1d1
}
.block__inner--2{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 background: #d1e7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
 <div class="block__inner--1">block 1</div>
 <div class="block__inner--2">block 2</div>
</div>
```